# Purchase event has been uploaded via Offline Conversions API, but the Event Set does not show any data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I followed the guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions

Unlike "regular" Event Sets, which includes a "Test Events" tab in its dashboard, offline event sets don't seem to have this feature. You must either upload a CSV or call the API.

However, the offline event set shows no data coming from the API at all; the history tab only shows the CSV uploads, which were "last received 10 days ago". It doesn't even include the test upload I made today.

**Is this a bug?** How long should I wait for the data to appear in the events manager for my offline event?

Sample call

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/<offline_event_set_id>/events?access_token=<system_user_access_token>

{
  "upload_tag": "store_data",
  "data": [
    {
      "match_keys": {
        "em": "<hashed>",
        "ph": "<hashed>"
      },
      "currency": "PHP",
      "value": 100,
      "event_id": "test",
      "event_name": "Purchase",
      "event_time": "1669633380",
      "custom_data": {
        "event_source": "in_store"
      },
      "action_source": "physical_store",
      "order_id": "test",
      "data_processing_options": []
    }
  ]
}
```

The response is as follows:

```
{"id":"<offline_event_set_id>","num_processed_entries":1}
```

Which seems to indicate that the event was uploaded successfully. But that event never shows up in the Overview tab of that offline event set.

Would appreciate any insights/guides elsewhere/answers, I've spent a few days on this with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The "error": I was encoding the `event_time` as a string, whereas Facebook expects this value to be an integer. After updating my POST body to correct that, the events started showing up within minutes in the Overview tab.

```
{
  "upload_tag": "store_data",
  "data": [
    {
      "match_keys": {
        "em": "<hashed>",
        "ph": "<hashed>"
      },
      "currency": "PHP",
      "value": 100,
      "event_id": "test",
      "event_name": "Purchase",
      "event_time": 1669633380,  // <-- The only change was removing the quotes
      "custom_data": {
        "event_source": "in_store"
      },
      "action_source": "physical_store",
      "order_id": "test",
      "data_processing_options": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I really wish Facebook had returned some kind of error or warning, but at least I found the issue. Be careful with your data types, people!